# Need help finishing a batch script to rename files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

i am writing a script to rename files based on date.

Files are generated every day from a server outputing them like this:

```
fil150807102600000001.txt
fil150807102600000002.txt
fil150807102600000003.txt
```

My goal with my script is to auto rename them to:

```
FILE-SRV1.DAAMMJJ_00000001
FILE-SRV1.DAAMMJJ_00000002
FILE-SRV1.DAAMMJJ_00000003
```

Manual steps I goes trought to achieve this are :

```
 1- format date to AAMMJJ (i am on a french computer, windows 7)
      set date=%date:~8,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
         echo %date%
         150807
 2- Now rename my file as expected
      set fname=fil150807102600000001.txt
      ren "%fname%" "FILE-SRV1.D%date%_%fname:~13,8%"   [strip off the first 
      13 char and leave the 8 last]
```

My file is correctely renamed.

now I want to script this to:

```
loop into the directory, 
find all file names starting by fil*
and rename them as needed
```

Here is my script assuming this script is run from  the folder where my original files are:

```
set date=%date:~8,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
for /f %%f in ('dir fil* /b') do ren %%f "FILE-SRV1.D%%date%%_%%f:~13,8%"
```

Result is:

Test for file existence

```
C:\test\bat>dir fil* /b
fil150807102600000001.txt
fil150807102600000002.txt
fil150807102600000003.txt
```

Running the scripts

```
C:\test\bat>script2.bat
C:\test\bat>set date=150807
C:\test\bat>for /F %f in ('dir fil* /b') do ren %f "FILE-SRV1.D%date%_%f:~13,8"
C:\test\bat>ren fil150807102600000001.txt "FILE-RV1.D%date%_fil150807102600000001.txt:~13,8"
Le nom de fichier existe déjà, ou le fichier est introuvable.

C:\test\bat>ren fil150807102600000002.txt "FILE-    SRV1.D%date%_fil150807102600000002.txt:~13,8"
Le nom de fichier existe déjà, ou le fichier
est introuvable.

C:\test\bat>ren fil150807102600000003.txt "FILE-SRV1.D%date%_fil150807102600000003.txt:~13,8"
Le nom de fichier existe déjà, ou le fichier
est introuvable.
```

Please your help will be well appreciated

Comment: Can you please add translations to the French text present?

Comment: Le nom de fichier existe déjà, ou le fichier est introuvable ==> file name already, exist out cannot find the file

Comment: -1 for the french, it is utterly unnecessary. You should make your demonstrations of issues, as simple as possible in order to ask your question, and in doing so you may even solve it yourself too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using too many `%` signs, it's not a good idea to assign to the `DATE` variable, and you can't do string operations on `FOR` variables directly (they are like `%%f` and you need something with a `%` at the end):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set dat=%date:~8,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2% 
for %%f in (fil*) do (
    SET "FILE=%%f"
    ren "%%f" "FILE-SRV1.D%dat%_!FILE:~13,8!"
)
```

(the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is required to use the `!` notation so the `FILE` variable gets updated each loop iteration.)

Comment: running this just rename the first file in list to FILE-SRV1.D150807_~13,8

Comment: Yeah, there was still a % too much,corrected.

Comment: Should be `for %%f in (fil*) do (` or `for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /A:-D fil*') do (`

Comment: That's super! friends!! IT's working like a charm! Thanks for all